# Tree view of the Document Library

Tags: document-library, office-365, document

I am trying to display 5 levels of document library in a tree view to show all the files within all folders and sub folders. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Is your folder quantity fixed or folders will be added/deleted anytime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side object model for this.

There is very good example of your problem:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37530/Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint

Comment: I am aware of this URL and it is not a feasible solution for my requirement as I need to host my library in Office 365(it contains some of the namespaces are not allowed in Cloud).

Comment: I was not aware you are using Sharepoint online. You can use client object model for this.

Comment: Also check: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/20212.aspx

Comment: The above URL is also redirecting to the codeproject URL which you have mentioned. I am trying to display this in a web part.

Comment: So, In sahrepoint online you need to use Sharepoint CSOM and iterate through all the documents and folders and bind that to your treeview. There is no out of the box solution for this.

Comment: @Ram you can write ECMA script to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I created a tree view collapsible menu for SharePoint Online. Following is the URL

http://dinushaonline.blogspot.com/2012/06/accordion-style-collapsible-menu-for.html

However try to use PnP JavaScript embed instead on directly modifying the masterpage.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EmbedJavaScript